# How to delete iBooks.app

Tags: macos, books

Is there any way to delete apps that were added by Apple in the Mavericks 10.9 update? In particular, I'm talking about iBooks.app. When I try to delete it, OS X tells me that it can't be because it's required by OS X.

Comment: Uninstalling iBooks and moving Books back to iTunes? http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1660388&highlight=ibooks You have to Kill the bookstoreagent service before you can get rid of the App.

Answer (score 1):

close iTunes

via **terminal.app**

```
sudo killall bookstoreagent
sudo tar -czf /Applications/iBooks.tar.gz /Applications/iBooks.app
sudo rm -fr /Applications/iBooks.app
```

keeps you a working backup, just in case you need it back:

```
cd /Applications
sudo tar -xzf /Applications/iBooks.tar.gz
```

there is no need to alter any other files, nor to play with LaunchAgents or Daemons. Once the App is gone, iTunes gains back the books functionality. I read some evil suggestions on the interwebs.

Comment: maybe you should provide warnings and explain what those do.

Answer (score 0):

1. Kill bookstoreagent
2. Remove the following files/folders:

   - `/Applications/iBooks.app/`
   - `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ibooks.plist`
   - `/private/var/folders/*/*/*/com.apple.iBooksX/`
   - `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iBooksX/`